# Why const char* implicitly converted to bool rather than std::string?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution, explicit, constructor-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct mystruct{
     mystruct(std::string s){
        
        std::cout<<__FUNCTION__ <<" String "<<s;
    }
    
     explicit mystruct(bool s) {
        
        std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<" Bool "<<s;
    }
};


int main()
{
    
    const char* c ="hello";
    
    mystruct obj(c);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
mystruct Bool 1
```

1. Why `const char*` implicitly converted to `bool` rather than `std::string`, though constructor requires `explicit` type ?
2. How the implicit conversion priority applies here?

Comment: Because it's a pointer, and all pointers can naturally be implicitly converted to `bool` values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: but the constructor is marked as `explicit`, why not it is referring to the type?

Comment: [Direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), which you are doing, is always explicit. It would be a different matter if you did [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) (like `mystruct obj = c;`), or used `c` in another context where a `mystruct` object was expected (like calling a function expecting a `mystruct` object by value).

Comment: You can use `std::enable_if` to select the desired constructor in this case.

Comment: `explicit` disables implicit conversion of `X` to `mystruct` , not of implicit conversion of arguments types to constructor.

Comment: @M.M: yes I understood, earlier I had assumptions that `explicit` meant also for argument type to constructor

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the implicit conversion from `const char*` to `bool` is qualified as standard conversion, while `const char*` to `std::string` is user-defined conversion. The former has higher ranking and wins in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

> A standard conversion sequence is always better than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence.

BTW: `mystruct obj(c);` performs [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization#Notes), `explicit` converting constructors including `mystruct::mystruct(bool)` are considered too. As the result, `c` is converted to `bool` then passed to `mystruct::mystruct(bool)` as argument to construct `obj`.

> Direct-initialization is more permissive than copy-initialization: copy-initialization only considers non-explicit constructors and non-explicit user-defined conversion functions, while direct-initialization considers all constructors and all user-defined conversion functions.

About [`explicit` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit),

> 1. Specifies that a constructor `or conversion function (since C++11)` `or deduction guide (since C++17)` is explicit, that is, it cannot be used for [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) and [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

Comment: In my humble opinion that's WEIRD. What's the point of `explicit`, then?

Comment: It stops accidental conversions, e.g: https://godbolt.org/z/heErYe or https://godbolt.org/z/7hWdon, if you couldn't call an explicit constructor in the way you've written it you'd never be able to call that constructor at all

Comment: @manuell It takes effect in [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), but doesn't make difference in direct initialization.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Not sure what you mean with second part of your comment, how about `mystruct obj( static_cast<bool>(c));` ? I think thats what OP expect to be required to call the explicit ctr

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I suppose they could have defined it that way, pretty awkward though

Comment: @manuell maybe it helps to think of it like that: What is explicit in the line `mystruct obj(c);` is that you are explicitly creating a `mystruct`, while you cannot call a `foo(mystruct)` with a `bool` directly. Its the creating of a `mystruct` that is explicit not the parameter type to the constructor

Answer (score 1):

"Why `const char*` implicitly converted to `bool` rather than `std::string`, though constructor requires `explicit` type ?":

- Standard conversion is preferred over user defined-conversions.

`char const*` is a pointer to constant character and a pointer can be implicitly converted to `bool` : in case it is `nullptr` it is converted to `false` otherwise to `true`.

- You used to see such effective conversion in conditions where you check whether the pointer is `NULL` or not so in case it is not `nulptr` we safely de-reference  it otherwise it has `nullptr` value thus it is not correct to de-reference it:

  ```
  int* ptr = nullptr;

  if(ptr) // false  because ptr has nullptr or NULL or 0 or 0x000000 address value
     std::cout << ptr << '\t' << *ptr << '\n'; // not executed

  ptr = new int(10); // valid and non-nullptr

  if(ptr) // non-nullptr so condition succeeds
     std::cout << ptr << '\t' << *ptr << '\n'; // 0FED155   10
   delete ptr; // free memory
  ```
- `explicit` constructor means it can only be called explicitly and the only way is through Direct Initialization like in your case:

  ```
  mystruct obj(c); // direct initialization
  mystruct obj = c; // copy-initialization. Error: constructor myStruct(bool) is `explicit`
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the already good answer. You can work around this by adding a [delegating constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/delegating-constructors?view=msvc-170) as in:

```
mystruct(const char* s):mystruct(std::string(s)) {}
```

Which will win over bool in overload resolution.

Another option is to avoid bool here and use a bool but something that carries more meaning. This could be an example of ['boolean blindness'](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/gk2le/boolean_blindness_why_bool_isnt_good_enough/)